# How can I make Python check which pixel a face is in?

Tags: python, computer-vision

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import win32api, win32con
import time

from PIL import ImageGrab

ImageBox = None
im = ImageGrab.grab(ImageBox)
im.save('screenshot.png')
im.close()
image = cv2.imread("screenshot.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.3,
        minNeighbors=3,
        minSize=(30, 30)
)

print("Found {0} Faces!".format(len(faces)))
```

This is the code I currently have and I need it to find the pixel coordinate of the face.

Comment: ...what? A face isn't *in* a specific pixel.

Comment: the code above checks for a face and then says whether it can find any faces, but i then want it to print what pixels the face covers

Comment: Doesn't the resulting `faces` contain this information?

Comment: okay im probably being really stupid. But if i print faces nothing happens, if i do "("Found {0} Faces!".format(len(faces)))" it will print how many faces it sees, i just wanna know the code to make it print the pixel coordinatess of the face

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Surely *something* happens if you use `print(faces)`?

Comment: it prints "()" just two brackets

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you can post your input image and output log/screenshot, then it might be helpful for others to reproduce/suggest